# How to calculate the size of data transferred between two machines in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, size, data, multiple-machines

I have two computers.

The first one is as a workstation. It runs the deep learning code and connects an AP by a wired connection.

The second one is as a robot's computer. It sends the video and other information from other sensors and connects an AP by a LAN card.

I'd like to know the data size of packets exchanged between them in real-time using commands in the terminal.

How do I measure data they transfer to each other via the network?

**Note:** I am using only local wireless LAN (no internet)

Comment: You really mean the size of data transferred? I'd go with an `iptables` rule then. If you only want to view the current transfer rate, take a look at `iptraf` or `iptraf-ng`

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more I'd say tcpdump is a good start

`tcpdump -s0 -ni <WIFI-DEVICE> host <ROBO-IP> -w data.pcap`

writes all data between the linux-machine and and the roboter to data.pcap.

From there you can analyze the data for example with

- scapy (python-lib)
- wireshark

You can skip the data.pcap file

- by using wireshark directly (requires X on the linux host) or
- by writing directly to stdout
  `tcpdump -s0 -ni <WIFI-DEVICE> host <ROBO-IP> -w -`

then you need a program that reads the packages from stdin and analyzes them:
`tcpdump -s0 -ni <WIFI-DEVICE> host <ROBO-IP> -w - | <ANALYZER_PROG>`

this ANALYZER_PROG could be written with scapy

For scapy solutions I'd also search on stack-overflow.

HTH

Comment: tcpdump: 192.168.1.194: SIOCETHTOOL(ETHTOOL_GET_TS_INFO) ioctl failed: No such device

Comment: @Redhwan what is your complete command?
hint evereything in <> is meant as a place holder.
you get your network devices with `ip a s`

Answer (score 1):

[`iftop`](https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) provides this functionality. On Ubuntu you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y iftop
```

If you want to monitor the traffic to a specific server, you can use the `-f filter code`, for instance:

```
iftop -f 'host <HOSTNAME/IP ADDRESS>'
```

You'll see something like that:

```
                12.5Kb           25.0Kb           37.5Kb           50.0Kb     62.5Kb
+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
10.184.240.3                 => 10.184.125.147               10.0Kb  8.00Kb  11.6Kb
                             <=                              2.75Kb  2.29Kb  2.86Kb
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TX:             cum:   58.0KB   peak:   54.2Kb      rates:   10.0Kb  8.00Kb  11.6Kb
RX:                    14.3KB           10.2Kb               2.75Kb  2.29Kb  2.86Kb
TOTAL:                 72.3KB           64.4Kb               12.8Kb  10.3Kb  14.5Kb
```

Of course there are different flags for the command that you could read in the manual.